# Passing models in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building my first AngularJS app comming from backbone. I have a list where the user can select an item. The goal is show the details of the selected item in a view below the list. The list-view and detail-view are both part of the main-view.

**my list view**

```
<div id="rfc-records" class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-repeat="record in records" ng-click="selectRow()" class="row select table-row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 center">
            {{record.id}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 center">
            {{record.rfcObject}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            {{record.rfcFunction}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            {{record.status}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{mii.utils.date.extToIntDate(record.firstProcessing)}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see I already added an event to each row: `ng-click="selectRow()"`.
It is unclear to me how to know the selected row in this function. I could do something like this :

```
ng-click="selectRow(record)
```

**MainController**

```
 $scope.selectRow = function(record){
    alert(record.id); // undefined
}
```

The result is undefined so this does not work. Plus this seems like a bad approach to pass the model back from the view to the controller. I might be able to get the application working but I have the feeling that I won't be using the paradigm as intended.

In backbone I would have a seperate view for each row where the model is bound to. But in Angular models aren't as explicit as in backbone.

In general I don't really understand how models work in Angular. R

> Regarding this example I have the following questions:
>
> 1. How do I know what item is selected in the list
> 2. Where should I put the `selectRow` function? In the controller of the Mainview or in the list-view directive?
> 3. How do I pass the selected model to the details-view.

Comment: The ng-repeat in your code will display all rows from your records list. Are you looking to display just a list of record ids and on clicking it, then move to a detail view for that record? Then come back to list and can do the same again

Comment: You should put the "selectRow" func in the controller. You dont even have your directive posted in the question. Same goes with your details-view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, passing current item into `ngClick` handler is pretty usual way to solve this task. I'm not sure why it's not working for you, it should. Here is the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Loqi9C5EES5QBPUNXH5a?p=preview) of this typical approach.

> In backbone I would have a seperate view for each row where the model is bound to. But in Angular models aren't as explicit as in backbone.

Actually Angular is even more elegant in this concern. You still have model available in every iterated row. You can refer current child scope as `this` in controller. So in your case if you don't want to pass `record` object into controller function on click, you can use `this` and it will point to the current scope object (remember that `ngRepeat` creates new child scope for every row):

```
$scope.selectRow = function() {
    alert(this.record.id);
};
```

and you don't have to pass anything in HTML:

```
ng-click="selectRow()"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/kN0vB6N6v7XnqASRSmAd?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, got it working!  Very elegant indeed. Could you maybe also provide an answer to question 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

ng-click and ng-repeat are in same div. You can add a new div in this repeated div like and this is works for me :

```
<div id="rfc-records" class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-repeat="record in records" class="row select table-row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 center">
            Select This item<input type=button ng-click="selectRow(record)">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 center">
            {{record.id}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 center">
            {{record.rfcObject}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            {{record.rfcFunction}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            {{record.status}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{mii.utils.date.extToIntDate(record.firstProcessing)}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```